# How to get Dynamic data in Horizontal Listview

Tags: android, json, parsing

**I am doing parsing  from url for getting data into  Horizontal Listview**
its working fine but its display only last value from json object .i have below pasted my json parsing and json.Please suggest me where i am doing wrong.

**This is my json**

```
 {
    "status": 1,
    "category": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "category_name_en": "car",
            "category_name_ar": "car",
            "description_en": "",
            "description_ar": "",
            "day": "monday,tuesday,wednesday,thursday,friday,saturday,sunday",
            "status": "A",
            "created_at": "Sep 4 2017 8:09 AM",
            "updated_at": "Sep 4 2017 8:09 AM",
            "sub_category": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "sub_category_name_en": "Audi",
                    "sub_category_name_ar": "Audi",
                    "sub_description_en": "",
                    "sub_description_ar": "",
                    "status": "A",
                    "created_at": "Sep 4 2017 8:10 AM",
                    "updated_at": "Sep 4 2017 8:10 AM"
                },
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "sub_category_name_en": "New",
                    "sub_category_name_ar": "New",
                    "sub_description_en": "",
                    "sub_description_ar": "",
                    "status": "A",
                    "created_at": "Sep 4 2017 9:45 AM",
                    "updated_at": "Sep 4 2017 9:45 AM"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "category_name_en": "Animal",
            "category_name_ar": "Animal",
            "description_en": "",
            "description_ar": "",
            "day": "monday,tuesday,wednesday,thursday,friday,saturday,sunday",
            "status": "A",
            "created_at": "Sep 4 2017 9:19 AM",
            "updated_at": "Sep 4 2017 9:19 AM",
            "sub_category": [
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "sub_category_name_en": "Dogs",
                    "sub_category_name_ar": "Dogs",
                    "sub_description_en": "",
                    "sub_description_ar": "",
                    "status": "A",
                    "created_at": "Sep 4 2017 9:20 AM",
                    "updated_at": "Sep 4 2017 9:20 AM"
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "sub_category_name_en": "Cat",
                    "sub_category_name_ar": "Cat",
                    "sub_description_en": "",
                    "sub_description_ar": "",
                    "status": "A",
                    "created_at": "Sep 4 2017 9:21 AM",
                    "updated_at": "Sep 4 2017 9:21 AM"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**This is my parsing**

Here i am doing my parsing , its return json object size right but it shows only last value

where i am wrong. Please Suggest me

```
public static ArrayList<CardData> PaeseBanner(String response) throws JSONException {
    ArrayList<CardData> alUser = new ArrayList<>();

    JSONObject jsonRoot = new JSONObject(response);

    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonRoot.getJSONArray("category");

    CardData LT = new CardData();

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

        JSONObject jsonObject2 = null;

        JSONArray jsonArray1 = jsonObject.getJSONArray("sub_category");

        for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray1.length(); j++) {

            jsonObject2 = jsonArray1.getJSONObject(j);

            LT.setSubcategory_name(jsonObject2.getString("sub_category_name_en"));

            alUser.add(LT);
        }

    }

    return alUser;
}
```

**This is my screen short**
[This is Screen Short](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFVD9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray1.length(); j++) {
    CardData LT = new CardData(); // Create new CardData object inside second for loop

    jsonObject2 = jsonArray1.getJSONObject(j);

    LT.setSubcategory_name(jsonObject2.getString("sub_category_name_en"));

    alUser.add(LT);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use these lines:

```
CardData LT = new CardData();
```

and

```
JSONObject jsonObject2 = null;
```

inside for loop. Like this:

```
public static ArrayList<CardData> PaeseBanner(String response) throws JSONException {
    ArrayList<CardData> alUser = new ArrayList<>();

    JSONObject jsonRoot = new JSONObject(response);

    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonRoot.getJSONArray("category");



    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        CardData LT = new CardData();

        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

        JSONArray jsonArray1 = jsonObject.getJSONArray("sub_category");

        for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray1.length(); j++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject2 = null;

            jsonObject2 = jsonArray1.getJSONObject(j);

            LT.setSubcategory_name(jsonObject2.getString("sub_category_name_en"));

            alUser.add(LT);
        }

    }

    return alUser;
}
```